# How can I set objects/items in my 2D game using cfg or json files instead of my current method?

Tags: java, json, game-engine, game-development

How can I read them from a json file that looks like or similar to

[{
"id": 1,
"name": "Key",
"x": "Milan Kundera",
"y": "The Unbearable Lightness of Being"
}
}]

How I currently handle objects and it doesn't seem to efficient

```
public class SuperObject {
    
    public BufferedImage image;
    public String name;
    public boolean collision = false;
    public int worldX, worldY;
    
    /* Draws the images to the screen */
    
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2, GamePanel gp) {
        int screenX = worldX - gp.player.worldX + gp.player.screenX;
        int screenY = worldY - gp.player.worldY + gp.player.screenY;
        
        
        if (worldX + gp.tileSize > gp.player.worldX - gp.player.screenX && 
            worldX - gp.tileSize < gp.player.worldX + gp.player.screenX &&
            worldY + gp.tileSize > gp.player.worldY - gp.player.screenY &&
            worldY - gp.tileSize < gp.player.worldY + gp.player.screenY) {
            
        g2.drawImage(image, screenX, screenY, gp.tileSize, gp.tileSize, null);  
        
        }   
    }
}
```

and for my individual object class, I will take a key for example

```
public Key() {
        
        name = "Key";
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/objects/key.png"));
        
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and to place them on the screen/map or however you want to look at it I have been using this method

```
public class AssetSetter {
    
    GamePanel gp;
    
    public AssetSetter(GamePanel gp) {
        this.gp = gp;
    }
    
    public void setObject() {
        gp.obj[0] = new Key();
        gp.obj[0].worldX = 23 * gp.tileSize;
        gp.obj[0].worldY = 7 * gp.tileSize;
        
        gp.obj[1] = new Key();
        gp.obj[1].worldX = 23 * gp.tileSize;
        gp.obj[1].worldY = 40 * gp.tileSize;
        
        gp.obj[1] = new Key();
        gp.obj[1].worldX = 37 * gp.tileSize;
        gp.obj[1].worldY = 7 * gp.tileSize;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: So what's the actual problem?